# Find value of $\prod(1+\alpha^2)$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, quartics

if $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are the roots of equation $x^4+4x^3-6x^2+7x-9$ then find $\prod(1+\alpha^2)$
I know

1. $\sum \alpha=-4$
2. $\sum \alpha\beta=-6$
3. $\sum \alpha\beta\gamma=-7$
4. $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta=-9$

I know the sum and products and other things about the roots but I am not being to rearrange them such that I am able to get the required answer

Comment: Your quartic polynomial is $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$.

Comment: Do you know about transformation of roots?

Comment: You say $\alpha$ is ONE of the roots, but then you use the notations $\prod (1 + \alpha^2)$ and $\sum\alpha$ in a way that makes one suspect that _this_ $\alpha$ is to run through the list of all four roots.

Answer (score 4):

Your polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ since it is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, hence it is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. The minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$ is given by

$$ \left[\underbrace{\left(x^4-6x^2-9\right)^2}_{\text{even part}}-\underbrace{\left(4x^3+7x\right)^2}_{\text{odd part}}\right]_{x\mapsto \sqrt{x}} = x^4-28x^3-38x^2+59x+81=g(x)$$
and
$$ \prod_\text{cyc}(1+\alpha^2) = g(-1) =\color{red}{13}.$$
As an alternative, the LHS is the determinant of $M^2+I$ where $M$ is the companion matrix of the original polynomial.

Comment: Hello Jack, I'm not quite familiar with your approach, but why do you evaluate $g(-1)$. I don't quite see it :-(

Comment: @Diger: the point is that $$ g(x)=\prod_{cyc}(x-\alpha^2) $$ hence $g(-1)$ is the quantity we want. On the other hand $g(-1)=1+28-38-59+81$ by the explicit construction of $g$ as the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Transforming roots from $\alpha$ to $1+\alpha^2$,

$$y=1+\alpha^2$$

$$\alpha=\sqrt{y-1}$$

As $\alpha$ satisfies our given polynomial, Substitute $\alpha$ into that.

We get new equation with roots $1+\alpha^2,1+\beta^2,\ldots$

$$(x-1)^2+4(x-1)\sqrt{x-1}-6(x-1)+7\sqrt{x-1}-9=0$$

Rearranging and squaring,

$$(x-1)^2(x-7)^2+81-18(x-1)(x-7)=(x-1)(4x+3)^2$$

$$(x^2+1-2x)(x^2+49-14x)+81-18(x^2+7-8x)=(x-1)(16x^2+9+24x)$$

$$x^4-32x^3+34x^2+45x+13=0$$

$$\text{Product of roots}=\frac{13}{1}=13$$

Comment: Can I know why my answer was downvoted?

Comment: Why is the resulting $q(x)$ a polynomial? You are plugging in square roots...

Comment: @Wojowu, Edited what I meant. I may not have been able to put it forward clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write it as $\;\prod(1+\alpha^2) = \prod\big((1+i\alpha) \cdot (1-i\alpha)\big)=\prod(1+i\alpha) \cdot \prod(1-i\alpha)\,$.

If $\,\alpha\,$ are the roots of $\,P(x)\,$, then the polynomial $\,Q(z)\,$ with roots $\,1+i \alpha\,$ is the result of the substitution $\,1+ix = z$ $\iff x = i(1-z)\,$. After routine calculations:

$$
Q(z) = P\big(i(1-z)\big) = z^4 - 4(1 - i) z^3 + 12(1 - i) z^2 - (16 - 5 i) z - (2 - 3 i)
$$

It follows from Vieta's relations that $\,\prod (1+i \alpha) = -(2-3i)\,$.

By a similar argument $\,\prod (1-i \alpha) = -(2+3i)\,$, so in the end $\,\prod(1+\alpha^2)= |2-3i|^2=13\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   For the particular problem here, we do not actually need to determine the full $\,Q(z)\,$, but just find the product of its roots i.e. the constant term $\,Q(0)\,$, which is a straightforward calculation: $\,Q(0)=P(i)=i^4+4i^3-6i^2+7i-9=1+6-9+(-4+7)i=-2+3i\,$.